# is it possible to Determine wether there is a hung transaction\request on IIS server?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

i am trying to use perfon counters and other server flags and constants .. but i cant find a solution. i want to write a piece of code that will tell me if there are any hung transactions on my IIS server

Comment: What kind of hung transactions? Database transactions? More detail is required.

Comment: @Kev i am developing a monitoring software. So i need to take into account "as many types of hung transactions as i can"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at perf counters we can determine this.